# What exactly can be the concept of possessing in this context?

Tags: mahabharata, atma, terminology, human

We frequently encounter the phenomenon of "someone possessing the others" in the scriptures. One example can be found [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19504/was-karnas-soul-possessed-by-narakasura). I provided below another example of kali possessing Nala.

> "Vrihadaswa said
>
> ...
>
> Kali, that vilest of the celestials, filled with wrath
>
> ...
>
> And when the gods had gone away, Kali said unto Dwapara, 'I am ill
> able, O Dwapara, to suppress my anger. **I shall possess Nala, deprive
> him of his kingdom**, and he shall no more sport with Bhima's daughter.
> Entering the dice, it behoveth thee to help me.'"
>
> [[Section 58, Nalopakhyana Parva, Vana Parva
> , The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03058.htm)

I think that it cannot be para kaya pravesa as it generally [happens between humans](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24707/who-was-the-sage-who-asked-his-disciples-to-guard-his-wife-while-he-was-away). But in the examples, it did not happen between humans and it happened between devtas/asuras and humans.

What exactly is possessing in this context?

Comment: I would have thought the literal one, like with demonic possession makes sense given the story. Do you have any reason to believe differently?

Comment: Also, this is clearly a mistranslation. Earlier in the same text Kali is clearly a Deva too

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa Since Kali is a devata, I think this phenomenon is different from apra kaya pravesa that happens between humans.

Comment: Possession happens between humans?

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa I mean para kaya pravesa. Please see the example I provided.

Comment: I see. Although possession both in Hinduism and outside has more mentions of the kind Kali does than para kaya pravesa, so it should be the standard definition. Although using that might not fit in the question heading.